# How do I convert a java class that has an arraylist to json

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson

I use the Gson  library and I have a class that has an arraylist as one of its members.
I add different object types to this arraylist then I serialize it to json

```
public class MethodParameter {
    private String className;
    private String methodName;
    private ArrayList parameters;

    public MethodParameter(){
        parameters = new ArrayList();
    }

    public String getClassName(){
        return className;
    }

    public String getMethodName(){
        return methodName;
    }

    public List<Object> getParameters(){
        return parameters;
    }

    public void setClassName(String value){
        className = value;
    }

    public void setMethodName(String value){
        methodName = value;
    }

    public void setParameters(ArrayList value){
        parameters = value;
    }
}
```

Then I convert as follows:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<MethodParameter>() {}.getType();
String json = gson.toJson(mp, type);
```

but all I get is :

`{"className":"MainClass","methodName":"Test","parameters":[]}`

Parameters is an arraylist to which I add classes of different types. How do I get it to create the correct json result?

Comment: show us the class and the example how are you using gson....

Comment: what is the problem there? have you added elements to the list?

Comment: The output looks ok if `parameters` is empty. Did you populate it? And if, can you show how?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and 2 things,

1. define the `MethodParameter.parameters` as a list (just a best practice)
2. the issue may be in the way you are manipulating the list in the `MethodParameter` object...

anyway here is a snippet working as you want it to do:

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MethodParameter mp = new MethodParameter();
    mp.setClassName(String.class.getCanonicalName());
    mp.setMethodName("replace");
    List<String> parametersList = new ArrayList<String>();
    parametersList.add("target");
    parametersList.add("sequence");
    mp.setParameters(parametersList);
    //
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<MethodParameter>() {
            }.getType();
    String json = gson.toJson(mp, type);
    System.out.println(json);
    }
```

but in my opinion you can generate the json by just doing this:

```
System.out.println(gson.toJson(mp, MethodParameter.class));
```